# Setting RequestHeaders for Get REST API in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have located some sample source code in visual basic to call a REST API. However, I need to modify the code by adding two request headers.

```
        ' Create the web request  
        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(sURI), HttpWebRequest)

        'Update request headers with request pairs Header1/"header1 value" and header2/"header2 value"
         ??? HttpWebRequest.headers.Add ????

        ' Get response  
        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        ' Get the response stream into a reader  
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the normal headers are "built-in," like so:

```
HttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Alternatively, you should be able to set any header you like with:

```
HttpWebRequest.Headers("Header1") = "Header1 value"
```

And another method in line with your original code:

```
HttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Header1", "Header1 value")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could consider using System.Net.WebClient.

Here is some code in C#

```
  using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
  {
    string userInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("user:password"));
    client.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + userInfo;
    client.DownloadString(url)
  }
```